# can messageDialogs contents be customized

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I am using message dialog and I want to customize the contents 
like increasing the titles fontsize and changing the fontweight.
also I want to use multi lines.

I want my message dialog to look like these

```
TITLE(bigger and bolder)
1- nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
2- kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
3- lllllllllllllllllllll
4- hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

                      OK
```

how can I customize the body and title?

Comment: I left my crystall ball in maintenance today, so we need you to answer a few questions in order to help you. Is this for Windows Forms? ASP.NET? WPF? Care to show the code you use to make your message dialog?

Comment: Why not create a customized dialog and handle the `DialogResult`Property of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a lot you can do, possibly better off creating your own.  However you can insert linbreaks via `Environment.NewLine` e.g.

```
MessageBox.Show("some text" + Environment.NewLine + "some more text");
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice and easy trick for creating one's own "rich format" message box is to put a `WebBrowser` control in a dialog window and feed this control with custom, local HTML. It gives reasonable formatting capabilities and it works regardless of whether it's WinForms or WPF.